# Short Circuit evaluation in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I am trying to see how to test short circuit evaluation in Pascal but not sure if doing it correctly. This is what I have so far.

```pascal
program shortcircuit;
var
   { local variable definition }
   a : integer;
   b : integer;

begin
   a := 8;
   b := 0;
   if( (b <> 0) and (a / b) ) then
      (* if condition is true then print the following *)
      writeln('...' )

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear what your question is, but you should try to provide a program that actually compiles before posting. This will help you answer your own questions.

The first problem you have is that Pascal has no concept of *automatically convert to boolean* that many C-derived languages do. You must test the inequity with zero explicitly.

I would also add an `else` clause to print when your test works successfully.

```
var
   { local variable definition }
   a : integer;
   b : integer;

begin
   a := 8;
   b := 0;
   if( (b <> 0) and ((a / b) <> 0.0) ) then
      (* if condition is true then print the following *)
      writeln('fooey' )
   else writeln('short circuited')
end.
```

http://tpcg.io/_HUNS7P

It is possible, should you make some minor modifications to the LHS of the `and` expression, that the compiler will notice you are hard-coding an attempt to divide by zero and complain.

Finally, Pascal always does short-circuit evaluation by default. You can disable it with a compiler directive, but that is always The Wrong Thing To Do.

For your example (avoiding a divide by zero error), the code will do the correct thing by default.

```
if (b <> 0) and some_predicate_function( a / b ) then ...
```

Though if you are just doing a checked divide, you could just make yourself a useful function that defaults to an acceptable value:

```
function checked_divide( a,b:integer; fooey:double = 0.0 ) : double;
  begin
    if b <> 0
      then result := a / b
      else result := fooey
  end;
```

Answer (score 2):

#### The notion of short-circuit evaluation is not part of the language:

> Boolean expressions have the property that their value may be known before the entire expression has been evaluated.
> Assume for example, that `X = 0`.
> Then the value of the expression
>
> ```pascal
> (x > 0) and (X < 10)
> ```
>
> is already known to be false after computation of the first factor, and the second need not be evaluated.
> Whether or not the second factor is evaluated is implementation-dependent.
> This means that you must assure that the second factor is well defined, independent of the value of the first factor.
> […]

Source:
Jensen, Kathleen; Wirth, Niklaus.
*Pascal – user manual and report* (4th revised ed.).
p. 32.
doi:10.1007/978‑1‑4612‑4450‑9.
ISBN 978‑0‑387‑97649‑5.

#### Therefore, you need to consult your compiler’s documentation.

[Delphi](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Boolean_short-circuit_evaluation_(Delphi_compiler_directive)) and the [FreePascal Compiler](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.2.0/prog/progsu4.html) have the `{$B+}`/`{$boolEval on}` and `{$B‑}`/`{$boolEval off}` (default) compiler directives, disabling and enabling short-circuit evaluation respectively.
The [GNU Pascal Compiler](https://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/and.html) recognizes `{$B+}`/`{$B‑}` too, plus `{$short‑circuit}`/`{$no‑short‑circuit}`.
However, the default is not *to guarantee* either, I don’t know, maybe for some SIMD optimizations.

#### Pascal “likes” writing things out.

Because, or *if* this implementation-dependence is dissatisfying or unwanted, the ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” introduces two other Boolean operators:

> A primary, a factor, a term, or a simple‑expression shall be designated an *operand*.
> Except for the `and_then` and `or_else` operators, the order of evaluation of the operands of a dyadic operator shall be implementation-dependent.
>
> <sup>NOTE —
> This means, for example, that the operands may be evaluated in textual order, or in reverse order, or in parallel, or they may not both be evaluated.</sup>

> ###### 6.8.3.3 Boolean operators
>
> […]
> In a term of the form `A and_then B`, the right operand shall be evaluated if and only if the left operand denotes the value `true`;
> the term shall denote the value `false` if the left operand denotes the value `false`;
> otherwise, the term shall denote the value denoted by the right operand.
> In a simple‑expression of the form `A or_else B`, the right operand shall be evaluated if and only if the left operand denotes the values `false`;
> the simple-expression shall denote the value `true` if the left operand denotes the value `true`;
> otherwise, the simple-expression denotes the value denoted by the right operand.

Unfortunately, of the previously mentioned compilers only the GNU Pascal Compiler supports `and_then`/`or_else`.
Generally speaking, if you want “short-circuit evaluation”, you have to write it out in Pascal (e. g. a nested `if` in lieu of `and_then`).

#### Experimentally determining your compiler’s behavior.

> I am trying to see how to test short circuit evaluation in Pascal but not sure if doing it correctly.

A test design would use `Boolean` `function`s with side-effects, particularly `writeLn`s, like so:

```pascal
program shortCircuitTest(output);
    
    function A: Boolean;
        begin
            writeLn('A');
            A := false;
        end;
    
    function B: Boolean;
        begin
            writeLn('B');
            B := true;
        end;
    
    { === MAIN ========= }
    begin
        if A and B then
        begin
            writeLn('then branch');
        end
        else
        begin
            writeLn('else branch');
        end;
    end.
```

However, this is only *an* indicator.
You *really* need to consult your compiler’s documentation to know the details.